# Need to point WWW to another ip without impacting mail delivery

Tags: dns-zone

I have a client domain.com and on his DNS zone there is:

> @   A     50.50.50.50
> www CNAME domain.com
> @   MX domain.com

Is it possible to change the WWW to

> WWW A     200.200.200.200

And in the HTML site of 50.50.50.50 I just do an HTML REDIRECT to [www.domain.com](http://www.domain.com)

Basically I want to know if I can point the website to another server without impacting the e-mail delivery (the e-mail migration will happen in the near future).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. That is why the web site was supposed to be [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) because you could have multiple services for the same domain server by different servers or the same server or any combination. Using service.example.com offers the maximum flexibility.

However nowadays people assume that [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) and example.com are the same. That is why you need the HTTP redirection you mention from old website domain.com to [www.domain.com](http://www.domain.com).

You should also plan to move the MX from domain.com to something like mail.domain.com or mx1.domain.com

Comment: Let me see if I understand:
1. Create a A record mail.domain.com -> 50.50.50.50
2. Change the MX to -> mail.domain.com
3. Make the changes to www as I want to on DNS and Redirect on html

This way the site will point to the new server (with and without www) but the mail will lookup to the old server and still work.

Is this corret? Thanks by the quick help :)

Comment: Yes, you got it right. Check the SPF record and make sure it includes "mx".

Comment: Your MX record will need to point to a name that exists, in case this isn't obvious. That is: Right now you have "domain.com MX domain.com" meaning "mail for domain.com is handled by the machine named domain.com" (slightly redundant, but whatever.) Then you have "domain.com A 50.50.50.50", which is the IP address that actually handles your mail. When you switch to "domain.com MX mail.domain.com", that says "mail for domain.com is handled by the machine mail.domain.com". Then you will need an A record for that: "mail.domain.com A 50.50.50.50" (assuming that machine isn't changing.)

Comment: (I spelled out the full names of the records, but they get abbreviated as follows: When defining records for "domain.com", "@"  means "domain.com" and "foo" means "foo.domain.com". So you would just write: "mail A 50.50.50.50".)